# Writing a Webextension for Thunderbird Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions, thunderbird

I am new in JavaScript/web extensions can someone tell me how web extensions work? And how I can write a web extension for my own?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I recomend you to read MDN for Mozilla Products.

**WebExtensions**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions

> An extension adds features and functions to a browser. It’s created using familiar web-based technologies—HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. It can take advantage of the same web APIs as JavaScript on a web page, but an extension also has access to its own set of JavaScript APIs. This means that you can do a lot more in an extension than you can with code in a web page.
>   To help illustrate how to develop extensions, we maintain a repository of simple example extensions at https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples. This article describes the WebExtension APIs used in that repository.

...

> These examples work in Firefox Nightly: most work in earlier versions of Firefox, but check the strict_min_version key in the extension's manifest.json to make sure.
>
> If you want to try out these examples, you have three main choices:
>
> - Clone the repository, then load the extension straight from its source directory, using the "Load Temporary Add-on" feature. The extension will stay loaded until you restart Firefox.
> - Clone the repository, then use the web-ext command line tool to run Firefox with the extension installed.
> - Clone the repository, then go to the build directory. This contains built and signed versions of all the examples, so you can just open them in Firefox (using File/Open File) and install them permanently, just like an extension you would install from addons.mozilla.org.

**Thunderbird Extensions**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Thunderbird_extensions

> **Getting started with Thunderbird**
>
> A brave, young developer wants to develop an add-on for Thunderbird. These links to help through this journey. Note: This documention series is not yet updated for version 60.
>
> - Start by reading the tutorial and learn how to build a Thunderbird extension.
>     (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Thunderbird_extensions/Building_a_Thunderbird_extension)
> - Also see Thunderbird 57-60 add-ons guide (https://wiki.mozilla.org/Thunderbird/Add-ons_Guide_57) for changes introduced in Thunderbird 60.
> - Read about the main windows (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Main_Windows) to learn about « thread pane », « preview pane », and « folder pane ».
> - Play with a demo add-on (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Thunderbird_extensions/Demo_Addon) that exercises some more advanced Thunderbird-specific features
> - Want to do even more? Don't reinvent the wheel: steal from the thunderbird-stdlib (https://github.com/protz/thunderbird-stdlib) project (doc here: [http://protz.github.io/thunderbird-stdlib/doc/symbols/*global*.html](http://protz.github.io/thunderbird-stdlib/doc/symbols/_global_.html)). Functions for dealing with messages (delete, archive, change tags, etc.) are included.
> - Haven't found what you need? Read the Thunderbird how-tos (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Thunderbird_extensions/HowTos); they contain many recipes for things extensions want to do.
> - Still stuck?  Ask in a community communication channel on the right.
> - Feeling really brave? Read the source using a fancy interface (http://doxygen.db48x.net/comm-central/html/); you can often find tests that demonstrate what you're trying to achieve.

**Thunderbird Extensions Developing**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Developing_WebExtensions_for_Thunderbird

> Being both Gecko based, Thunderbird supports many of the APIs Firefox supports, with some differences, see browser compatibility for manifest.json and browser support for JavaScript APIs for details. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Browser_compatibility_for_manifest.json)